# Haxe/OpenFL: How do I override GameActivity.java

Tags: android, haxe, openfl

Is there a way to override parts of an OpenFL-Template without modifying the installed version? Specifically I want to modify `templates/android/src/org/haxe/nme/GameActivity.java`.

I'm aware of examples that override `AndroidManifest.xml` via:

```
<template
    path="templates/android/AndroidManifest.xml"
    rename="AndroidManifest.xml"
    if="android"
/>
```

This works fine, but not for the desired Java-File.

I also tried to make a copy of the `templates`-Folder and put `<template path="templates" />` in my `project.xml`-File, as described in the docs. (I even tried `<`**templates**` path="templates" /> because I *think* the docs are wrong.) Didn't work.

My custom `GameActivity.java` is ignored. Is there a way?

(I'm using Haxe 3.1.0-rc3, OpenFL 1.0.6 with OpenFL-native 1.0.7.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override MainActivity.java (like you do for AndroidManifiest.xml). MainActivity extends GameActivity and you can override some parts. Or write your own 'GameActivity'.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain this correctly: I have my customised GameActivity.java but I have to modify the distribution because I can't get the path override mechanism to work. This mechanism exists, is documented, and works fine for AndroidManifest.xml. I just don't know how to make it work with the Java files.

Comment: This mechanism also work to .java files to. Take a look on this - https://github.com/sergey-miryanov/ExtensionsPack/blob/master/MainActivity.java. As can you see MainActivity extends custom java class. Ans MainActivity copied to export also as a template.

Comment: Ok, your example is very helpful, I managed to override MainActivity.java. I couldn't _replace_ GameActivity.java, but I think I will be able to manipulate the MainView this way.